# Payment Success But onProductPurchased is not called second time it calls

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

onProductPurchased just called if i press my purchase Button at the second time. At the second Time no Purchase windows appear but onProductPurchased is called this **time** correctly.

i use https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3/issues/100.

I can shop when I first click, but I can not get it for the second time.

This is my activity :

http://pasted.co/82bc6301

Answer (score 0):

bp.consumePurchase("YOUR PRODUCT ID FROM GOOGLE PLAY CONSOLE HERE");

Hi, this is answer of my ask.

You must use if you want to sell again.

Thanks.